# What is required to maintain PR status in Germany?

Tags: germany, immigration, residency

I currently hold the German Permanent Resident status. I am taking up a job in a non-European country, but may get back to Germany at a later point (in a few years). Is it possible for me to maintain my PR until that time? What are the basic requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to maintain my PR until that time?

No. Not really.

- In general, a [Section 9 Permanent Residence Permit](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0125) expires *6 months* after you have left the country, [§ 51 Ⅰ ₇ AufHG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1050).
- However, it *never* expires after having lived for 15 years in the FRG, [§ 51 Ⅱ 1 AufHG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1050), *unless* the FRG does not want you here (anymore), e. g. (convicted) criminals/terrorists, or if you do not have the (economic) means to live here by yourself.
- (For a [Section 9a EU-PR](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0143) longer periods apply, see [§ 51 Ⅸ AufHG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1050).)

Nevertheless, previous times in Germany will contribute to your *reapplication*.

> What are the basic requirements?

I’d say, if you *definitely* intend to eventually return and already got some *substantial* “social sphere” in Germany, simply travel every 6 months to Germany. Legally, all you need is the entry stamp in your passport. Many people around the globe do this (for *various* countries), so it’s not an unusual practice.

Comment: Thank you, traveling every 6 months would not be easily possible for me. What is the best way to contact a lawyer regarding this in Germany?

Comment: _All practicing_ lawyers are _compulsory_ members of a/the bar association, 12 Ⅲ BRAO. The respective local bar association maintains a directory of lawyers and feeds their data to the [National Register of Lawyers](https://www.bea-brak.de/bravsearch/index.brak), 31 BRAO. In principle _any_ lawyer can assist you, but if there are too many lawyers for your location, you may choose „Migrationsrecht“ as “Professional subtitle”. Language proficiency is not recorded in the directory, but the respective lawyer’s website usually indicates “unusual” languages (i. e. _other_ than German or English).

Comment: Most Embassies will have a list of lawyers that claims they speak that country's language (e.g at the French consulate in Berlin has a list of French-speaking lawyers https://de.ambafrance.org/Liste-des-avocats-et-notaires-francophones-18681)

Comment: No, those are German lawyers but French-speaking, they aren't French-juridiction lawyers @phoog

Comment: @NicolasFormichella yes, I see that I was confused.  I was thinking of the German embassy in France rather than the French embassy in Germany.  I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

An *unbefristete Aufenthaltserlaubnis* generally lapses after 6 months absence. The *Blue Card EU* generally lapses after 12 months absence. But there are exceptions. This may be extended if *the absence is in the interest of Germany,* which may include the interests of German industry. You should definitely check your specific case with a specialized lawyer in Germany before you leave.

Comment: How do I prove the interest of Germany? What do I need to file (and where?) I am in an academic job (Asst. Prof.) if it changes anything.

Comment: @RahulGopinath, talk to a lawyer where you live.

Comment: What is the best way to arrange for a consultation (in English) with a lawyer in Germany? any online websites I can look up?

Comment: @RahulGopinath, any lawyer's office should speak enough English to say if they do consult in English. As to selecting one, sorry, I'm not qualified to answer that one.